# Who knows how many hops a client is using?

Tags: relays, configuration

If an user changes the number of hops of his/her Tor client to some non-standard number (i.e. !=3), what nodes and who else in the circuit would know how many hops this client is using?.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure on this, so someone who knows should confirm or correct, but as I understand, only the client knows, unless you use just a single hop, in which case everybody knows.

It goes like this: The **guard** relay can see the difference between an incoming connection *from a client* vs. from *another relay*. (<--This is this thing I'm not 100% on.) The **exit** relay obviously knows the difference between an outgoing connection *to a final destination* vs. to *another relay*. If the **guard** relay is the *same* as the **exit** relay, then it knows that the number of hops is *one*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if the nodes B connect with C and C connect with D, and if BCD are co-operation, maybe they know your IP address and certainly your number of nodes, I'm not sure